# Handling application level focus in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, joptionpane

I am trying to minimize the application when it loses focus or when clicked outside the application.

I use the below method to minimize the application when `JFrame` loses focus:

```
frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
```

Since I am using `JOptionPane` which gains focus and the `JFrame` loses focus - causing the application to get minimized.

Is there any way to handle focus at the application level?

Comment: How about setting a flag for the focus listener to check just before showing the option pane? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This application is having 100's of 'JOptionPane', which makes hard to set flag before and after the 'JOptionPane'. So i am trying to know is there any other workaround without editing code around each 'JOptionPane'.

Comment: Is there any method window's level to know no component /JoptionPane is focused at that moment?. So, when the focus listener finds the JFrame lost focus and no other component /JoptionPane in that application has focus, we can setState to ICONIFIED.

Comment: Oh, good point.. See [`Window.getWindows()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--). The visible component of an option pane is a dialog, which inherits from `Window`. You might start there. Finding out if it has focus would require a little hacking into the components it contains.